# "Weights sum to zero, can’t be normalized" Error in treemap of plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am applying treemap function of plothly.express with COVID-19 data.

```
fig = px.treemap(df_tm, path=['world', 'continent', 'Country_Region'], values='Fatalities',
                  color='Fatalities', hover_data=['Country_Region'],
                  color_continuous_scale='dense', title='Current share of Worldwide COVID19 Cases')
```

However, I get 'Weights sum to zero, can’t be normalized' error message.
So, In order to solve this problem, I check my data, but there is no negative balance.

I don't know what to do. I study this with kaggle data.

https://www.kaggle.com/anshuls235/covid19-explained-through-visualizations

Comment: are you able to solve this?

Comment: I was able to solve it by removing all zero values from my data.

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled into the same problem, and my solution was: just checking for negative balances is not enough. You must also eliminate rows in the data frame you use for the plot that have a zero value in the column that is passed as value to the treemap plot function. Which makes sense: it's hard to print a zero area!
So my solution basically was to run

```
df_plot = df_plot[df_plot['value']!=0]
```

before calling `px.treemap` (with the column "value" in df_plot containing the values for the treemap)....and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: But in the given link (provided in the description of the question)
, the author has the ZERO values in the column 'Fatalities', and still able to produce the plot without any error.

How is it so?